# How to assign callback return value to a variable in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose.find()` function to check the user's credentials.

The `findUser` function will receive, from the `.find()`, `error` and `data` arguments.

I want to store on a variable wether the `.find()` method has found something that matches the query or not.

Instead, my `console.log(logged)` is displaying a lot of query information about the MongoDB operation.

```
var logged = UserModel.find(
          { username: username, password: password}, findUser );

console.log(logged);

var findUser = function (err, data) {
    (data.length) ? return true : return false;
};
```

How can I **return a true or false** from `mongoose.find()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that nodejs is async non-io blocking so any database operation will run async and probably your variable won't be assigned as you want.

I like to use promises in my flow control, in my case I use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which is a very cool promise library, you could do something like this (assuming express here):

```
 var BPromise = require('bluebird'),
 mongoose = BPromise.promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
// etc etc load your model here
//---------------------------------
    var thiz = this;
    thiz.logged = false;
    var myPromises = [];

    myPromises.push(
        UserModel.find({ username: username, password: password}).execAsync().then(function(data){
            thiz.logged = (data.length>0);
        })
    );
```

//wait for all the promises to complete in case you have more than one

```
BPromise.all(myPromises).then(function(){
 // do whatever you need...
});
```